# Falta traducción "EMAIL SETTINGS" en la sección de "Edición de perfil y configuración"

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

Cómo pueden ver, aquí dice "EMAIL SETTINGS" y creo que debería estar en español y decir "Configuración de correo electrónico"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]